# Problem on the management of django static file

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using apache+mod_wsgi+django. I come across with this situation. I have a webpage shown in the browser but without the css style which ought to be there supposedly. Here is my configuration on the setting.py and apache_django_wsgi.conf.

setting py:

```
import os.path
import posixpath

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
'/Users/.../static',
'/Users/.../static',
'/Users/.../static',
'/var/Project/static',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
 #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
 )
```

apache_django_wsgi:

```
Alias /static/ /var/Project/static/
<Directory /var/Project/static>
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

so where do I do wrong?

And then when I try "python manage.py findstatic css/main.css" it returns me the error message like these:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 35, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
self.validate()
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 338, in get_server_version
self.cursor()
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 71, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 170, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)")
```

Updates: Um..I think the path is right because when I check the error_log, I found that the server can locate the css/js. It just deny my access. The message is like these:

```
 client denied by server configuration: /var/Project/static/js/jquery.min.js, referer: http://<server>
```

So can anyone teach me how I can fix it? Does it have anything to do with the sql server?

Comment: You mysql connection is misconfigured. Test your mysql connection first.

Comment: That can't be your Apache configuration, else you have truly stuffed it up. Where is the opening <Directory /var/.../static> corresponding to the </Directory> closing. Include the proper configuration and don't edit out bits.

Answer (score 0):

Your traceback has nothing to do with static files. Check your `DATABASE_*` or `DATABASES` settings to match your environment. Check also if you mysql daemon is running (`ps aux | grep mysql` in ubuntu). After this traceback is gone, you have to do `python manage.py collectstatic` which will copy all your static files into one location Apache can serve it from.

Comment: I have all static file collected before. And all the css/js are in the place under the /var/.../static